# Python: Convert time expressed in seconds to datetime for a series

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a column of times expressed as seconds since Jan 1, 1990, that I need to convert to a DateTime.  I can figure out how to do this for a constant (e.g. add 10 seconds), but not a series or column.

I eventually tried writing a loop to do this one row at a time.  (Probably not the right way, and I'm new to python).

This code works for a single row:

```
def addSecs(secs):
    fulldate = datetime(1990,1,1)
    fulldate = fulldate + timedelta(seconds=secs)
    return fulldate

    b= addSecs(intag112['outTags_1_2'].iloc[1])

print(b)
```

> 2018-06-20 01:05:13

Does anyone know an easy way to do this for a whole column in a dataframe?

I tried this:

```
for i in range(len(intag112)):
    intag112['TransactionTime'].iloc[i]=addSecs(intag112['outTags_1_2'].iloc[i])
```

but it errored out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with column (series) in `DataFrame` you can use `apply` method, for example:

```
import datetime
# New column 'datetime' is created from old 'seconds'
df['datetime'] = df['seconds'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
```

Check [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for more examples. Overall advice - try to think in terms of vectors (or series) of values. Most operations in pandas can be done with entire series or even dataframe.